# CSS trigger hover only for top element

Tags: css

Is there elegant solution to hover only for top element, not for underlying; or i should to do this using javascript?

```
<div class="WithHover1">
   <div class="WithHover2">
       I am Top and I want to be the only div hightlighted
   </div>
   I want to be hightlighted too, but I dont want to be hightlighted when the nested one is
</div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is the "top" element? It is currently ambiguous.

Comment: Why don't you just wrap the "bottom" text in another element?  Check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this in just CSS, yet. The has selector is in draft for level 4/5 (I forget) CSS selectors, which will be awesome.

For now, javascript/jquery would be the easiest and most practical method.

```
$(".WithHover2").mouseover(function() {
    $(".WithHover1").removeClass("highlight");
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a CSS3 solution, using the `::after` pseudo-element, with a bottom border that overrides the background color of the bottom text.

The negative `z-index` prevents the border from covering up the text, and `overflow: hidden` prevents `WithHover1` from expanding due to the large border.

It works in IE11 (at least), Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera:

```css
div.WithHover1 {
  font: 14px verdana;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.WithHover1:hover {
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

div.WithHover2:hover {
  background: orange;
}

div.WithHover2:hover::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1000px solid white;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="WithHover1">
  <div class="WithHover2">
    I am Top and I want to be the only div highlighted
  </div>
  I want to be highlighted too, but I dont want to be highlighted when the nested one is.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This isn't what you want?  Your post wasn't that clear to me what you needed when hovering over each.

```css
.WithHover2:hover, .WithHover3:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="WithHover1">
   <div class="WithHover2">
       I want to be the only div hightlighted
   </div>
   <div class="WithHover3">
       I dont want to be hightlighted when the nested one is
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I couldn't tell if this is what he was asking for, I believe so - maybe, however I couldn't tell if he wanted them to be interchangable highlights, however the nested would take priority.

Comment: the top element is `div.WithHover1`

Comment: How are people down-voting this when the question was so vague?

Comment: @im1dermike Your solution hightlights `div.WithHover2` which isn't the top element... You haven't answer the question.

Comment: @Akarienta: The question isn't as clear as it should be.  Do they want to hover over WithHover1 and only see WithHover2 highlighted?  Why don't they wrap the text in WithHover1 in another element so they can do it all in CSS?

Comment: @im1dermike I suppose that there is a commutation between texts for `div.WithHover1` and `div.WithHover2` because if it wasn't it would be too trivial and the author wouldn't mention JavaScript.

Comment: @Akarienta: I think they author is complicating what they want to do by not just changing the HTML. I updated my snippet with what I think they want to do.